# force close cause HTTP entity may not be null

Tags: android

here a full code asyntask to Send Data Http

```
private class MyAsyncTaskPupuk extends AsyncTask<Void,Object ,Void> {

boolean bNodata=false;
boolean bError=false;
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    bNodata=false;
    bError=false;
    recordCount=cursorSend.getCount();
    if (recordCount<=0){//
        bNodata=true;
        return null;
    }
    cursorSend.moveToFirst();
    publishProgress(0,"Sending data started");
    //SystemClock.sleep(1000);
    CHamaRecord rec=new CHamaRecord();
    for (int i=0; i<recordCount; i++){
        if (isCancelled()) break;
        rec.lID=cursorSend.getLong(0);
        rec.dLongitude=cursorSend.getDouble(1);
        rec.dLatitude=cursorSend.getDouble(2);
        rec.dAccuracy=cursorSend.getDouble(3);
        rec.sFilename=cursorSend.getString(4);
        rec.nUserId=cursorSend.getInt(5);
        rec.nRate=cursorSend.getInt(6);
        rec.lDate=cursorSend.getLong(7);
        rec.sSent=cursorSend.getString(8);
        rec.IDSite=cursorSend.getString(9);
        rec.alamatSite=cursorSend.getString(10);
        rec.komoditas=cursorSend.getString(11);
        rec.luasSite=cursorSend.getString(12);
        rec.petugas=cursorSend.getString(13);
        rec.jnsHama=cursorSend.getString(14);
        rec.jmlHama=cursorSend.getString(15);
        rec.sn=cursorSend.getString(16);
        rec.pn=cursorSend.getString(17);
        rec.manufaktur=cursorSend.getString(18);
        rec.lblHama=cursorSend.getString(19);
        rec.lblKomoditas=cursorSend.getString(20);
        rec.lblPetugas=cursorSend.getString(21);
        publishProgress(1,i,rec);
        if (!SendDataFoto(rec)){
            recordCount=i;
            bError=true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            //change flag sent
            rec.sSent=CGeneral.strSent;
            cDBPupuk.updateEntry(rec.lID, rec);
        }
        cursorSend.moveToNext();
    }
    return null;
}//doInBackground

private boolean SendDataFoto(CHamaRecord rec){


        String slon=String.format("%f", rec.dLongitude);
        String slat=String.format("%f", rec.dLatitude);
        String sacc=String.format("%f", rec.dAccuracy);
        String srate=String.format("%d",rec.nRate);
        String sid=String.format("%d",rec.nUserId);
        String ids=String.format(rec.IDSite);
        String alt=String.format(rec.alamatSite);
        String kmd=String.format(rec.komoditas);
        String ls=String.format(rec.luasSite);
        String op=String.format(rec.petugas);
        String jns=String.format(rec.jnsHama);
        String jml=String.format(rec.jmlHama);
        String sn=String.format(rec.sn);
        String pn=String.format(rec.pn);
        String mFact=String.format(rec.manufaktur);
        String lblhama=String.format(rec.lblHama);
        String lblKomoditas=String.format(rec.lblKomoditas);

        File file=new File(rec.sFilename);
        String sfname=file.getName();
        String cfname=file.getName();
        int i=0;
        String lfname=rec.sFilename;
        sfname = sfname.substring(0, sfname.lastIndexOf("."));
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date(rec.lDate));
        String sdat=CUtilities.DateToString(cal);


        String url;
        String spupuk;
        if (CGeneral.nPupukOrPelihara==CGeneral.ACTIVITY_FOR_PUPUK){
            url = CGlobalConfig.getURLRcvrPupuk();
            spupuk="Hama";
        }
        else{
            url = CGlobalConfig.getURLRcvrPeliharaImage();
            spupuk="pelihara";
        }

        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(lfname);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();

        HttpEntity entity=null;

        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(ba, spupuk+"_"+cfname);
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("image", bab);
            reqEntity.addPart("category", new StringBody(spupuk));
            reqEntity.addPart("file_name", new StringBody(spupuk+"_"+cfname));
            reqEntity.addPart("rate", new StringBody(srate));
            reqEntity.addPart("tgl", new StringBody(sdat));
            reqEntity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody(sid));
            reqEntity.addPart("latitude", new StringBody(slat));
            reqEntity.addPart("longitude", new StringBody(slon));
            reqEntity.addPart("accuracy", new StringBody(sacc));
            reqEntity.addPart("id_site", new StringBody(ids));
            reqEntity.addPart("alamat_site", new StringBody(alt));
            reqEntity.addPart("komoditas", new StringBody(kmd));
            reqEntity.addPart("luas_area", new StringBody(ls));
            reqEntity.addPart("petugas", new StringBody(op));
            reqEntity.addPart("jenis_hama", new StringBody(jns));
            reqEntity.addPart("jumlah_hama", new StringBody(jml));
            reqEntity.addPart("serial", new StringBody(sn));
            reqEntity.addPart("p_number", new StringBody(pn));
            reqEntity.addPart("manufaktur", new StringBody(mFact));

            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            entity = response.getEntity();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
        String temp = null;
        try {
            temp = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        if (temp.compareTo("SUCCESS") == 0) {
            publishProgress(0,"Send Ok");
            SystemClock.sleep(500);
            return true;
        }
        else{
            publishProgress(0,"Send Fail");
            return false;               
        }   

    }

@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... arg) {
        Integer oi=(Integer)arg[0];
        String oStr;
        CHamaRecord rec;
        int flag=oi.intValue();
        int nVal;
        String str;
        TextView tvStatus=(TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendStatus);
        TextView tview;
        switch (flag) {
        case 0 :
            oStr=(String)arg[1];
            tvStatus.setText(oStr);
            break;
        case 1 :
            oi=(Integer)arg[1];
            rec=(CHamaRecord)arg[2];
            nVal=oi.intValue();
            str="Send record #"+String.format("%d",nVal);
            tvStatus.setText(str);
            str=String.format("%d", rec.lID);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendID);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format(rec.IDSite);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendIDSite);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format(rec.alamatSite);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendAlamat);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format(rec.lblKomoditas);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendKomoditas);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format(rec.luasSite);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendLuas);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format(rec.lblPetugas);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendPetugas);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format(rec.lblHama);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendJenis);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format(rec.jmlHama);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendJumlah);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format(rec.sn);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendSerial);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format(rec.pn);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendProduk);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format(rec.manufaktur);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendManufaktur);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format("%+3.5f", rec.dLongitude);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendLongitude);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format("%+3.5f", rec.dLatitude);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendLatitude);  
            tview.setText(str);
            /*str=String.format("%2.2f", rec.dAccuracy);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendAccuracy);  
            tview.setText(str);*/
            Date dt=new Date(rec.lDate);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendDate);  
            tview.setText(dt.toLocaleString());
            /*str=String.format("%d", rec.nRate);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendRating);  
            tview.setText(str);
            str=String.format("%d", rec.nUserId);
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendOperator);  
            tview.setText(str); */
            File file=new File(rec.sFilename);
            String fname=file.getName();
            tview = (TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendFilename);  
            tview.setText(fname);
            break;
        }
    }   
    //
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        TextView tvStatus=(TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendStatus);
        if (bNodata){
            tvStatus.setText("No data to be sent!!!");              
        }else {
            if (bError){
                tvStatus.setText("Fail at record #"+String.format("%d",recordCount));
            }
            else {
                tvStatus.setText("Sending Data : Finished");
            }
        }
//          dismissDialog(CGeneral.DIALOG_SEND);
    }
    protected void onCancelled(Void unused) {
        dismissDialog(CGeneral.DIALOG_SEND);
    }

}
```

the application work but
when i put wrong url or connection timeout, the application is force close .

here is my logcat

```
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP entity may not be null
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:110)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:146)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at hariff.ltis.inputhama.CInputHamaApp$MyAsyncTaskPupuk.SendDataFoto(CInputHamaApp.java:1307)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at hariff.ltis.inputhama.CInputHamaApp$MyAsyncTaskPupuk.doInBackground(CInputHamaApp.java:1040)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at hariff.ltis.inputhama.CInputHamaApp$MyAsyncTaskPupuk.doInBackground(CInputHamaApp.java:1)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-25 10:11:27.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2587):     ... 4 more
01-25 10:11:27.570: DEBUG/u-blox(1308): ublox_stop :
01-25 10:11:27.570: WARN/ActivityManager(1308):   Force finishing activity hariff.ltis.mainmenu/hariff.ltis.inputhama.CInputHamaApp
```

force close in line `temp = EntityUtils.toString(entity);`

how to fix that? so when i put wrong url or connection timeout, the application not force close and display message `"Send Failed"`.
?

BR

Alex

Comment: have you put Internet permission in manifest file

Comment: yes, before i put true url and it works. but now the problem is force close when i use wrong url or timeout.

Comment: The exception is pretty clear, the entity passed into [EntityUtils.toString()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0-beta2/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.java#106) is NULL. Check the value before calling `temp = EntityUtils.toString(entity);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an `HttpResponse` there, check it *before* you try to use the entity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html

```
int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); 
String message = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
```

And here are the constants Apache uses for the codes (they're standard HTTP, but since you're using `HttpClient` you can refer to these to see if you got a response you expect, or not): http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html

If the request gets to the server and fails, the response will let you know (for "wrong url" such as not even resolving the host, the connection will timeout, but that's not the error you're getting). And, even after that, I believe you should still check that the entity is not null before you pass it to `EntityUtils` (if it is null, something else unexpected went wrong, bail out).

Here's an example that should point you in the right direction (I would not recommend just copying/pasting it, but rather trying to understand it; this is a broad generalization, you may want to just check for standard OK responses, not redirects, and or your server side may be doing something non-standard, that depends on the server):

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
  String response = null;
  String message = null;
  int code = -1;
  try {
     httpResponse = client.execute(request);
     code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
     message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

     Log.i("LOG_TAG", "HTTP response -- code:" + code + "  message:" + message);

     if (code >= 200 && code <= 399) {
        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "got valid HTTP response code (200-399) processing response entity");
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
           InputStream instream = null;
           try {
              instream = entity.getContent();
              // convert stream if gzip header present in response
              Header contentEncoding = httpResponse.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
              if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                 instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
              }
              response = convertStreamToString(instream);
           } finally {
              if (instream != null) {
                 instream.close();
              }
           }
        }
     } else {
        // GOT SOME NON-VALID CODE, 404 (not found), 5xx (error), etc (log this, react to this, whatever, but you can't just use the "entity")
     }
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException("ERROR:" + e.getMessage(), e);
  } catch (IOException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException("ERROR:" + e.getMessage(), e);
  } finally {
     // shutdown connections
     client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
  }
```

In general an HTTP response code between 200 and 399 is a success or redirect, and 4xx, 5xx are errors. Here's some more info on HTTP response codes in general: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: can you give me a sample code? im newbie in android. @Charlie Collins

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a more specific example of how you might check the HttpResponse status code and message BEFORE you try to get the entity from it (you can't just get the entity, it WILL be null if something went wrong with the request, or on the server, etc).

Comment: I don't know how to add any further information to the answer here to make things any clearer. This has been stated multiple times, DON'T ASSUME THE ENTITY IS NON-NULL. You are getting an NPE in the line "temp = EntityUtils.toString(entity);" because the ENTITY IS NULL. Check the RESPONSE code/status BEFORE using "response.getEntity()" as I have shown in my answer. If you don't try to use a NULL entity, you won't get a NullPointerException and you're app won't FC.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep request time out and socket exception by the following code.

```
    try{
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 20000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 20000);
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

         .................................
         ..................................
          ...................................

           httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            entity = response.getEntity();



        }catch(ConnectTimeoutException e){
                //Do whatever you want here when you get timeout in connection
        }catch(SocketTimeoutException scte){
                // Do whatever you want here when you get sockettimeout exception...

        }catch(Exception e){
         //Do whatever you want here when you get unexpected exception... It is root exception . So whatever exception you didn't catch in the above, the control obviously gets into this block.
}
```

Even you can return in catch blocks some default results whatever you want.

Comment: Using other reasonable settings is also a good idea, but he's using DefaultHttpClient, which already has some reasonable defaults. And, he already has catch statements (though nothing wrapped up in finally, but that's a different issue). Timeouts and exceptions are NOT the problem, he's simply trying to use the entity when and where the is no entity.

Comment: i add yor code but still force close : http may not be null in line `temp = EntityUtils.toString(entity);`

Comment: @CharlieCollins Yeah. You are right. As he asked for the timeout at the end, I have shown to catch the exception. +1 Your answer is good to handle all other and as well as he can rule it out when the entity is null if the problem is still unknown.

Comment: @Alexbelek Then it might not be related to the connection timeout. I have just shown you how to catch the connectionTimeout and socket.... But did you try CharlieCollins' answer? Check it for null and even trace what condition you are getting null in.

Comment: @Appu i tried but i cant understand. can you give me some code? im newbie.

Comment: @Alexbelek Any progress in your present code? Or you are getting still the same errors?